# The Pause monad

Tags: haskell, monads, coroutine, monad-transformers, free-monad

Monads can do many amazing, crazy things. They can create variables which hold a superposition of values. They can allow you to access data from the future before you compute it. They can allow you to write destructive updates, but not really. And then the continuation monad allows you to *break people's minds!* Ususally your own. ;-)

But here's a challenge: Can you make a monad which can be *paused*?

```
data Pause s x
instance Monad (Pause s)
mutate :: (s -> s) -> Pause s ()
yield :: Pause s ()
step :: s -> Pause s () -> (s, Maybe (Pause s ()))
```

The `Pause` monad is a kind of state monad (hence `mutate`, with the obvious semantics). Normally a monad like this has some sort of "run" function, which runs the computation and hands you back the final state. But `Pause` is different: It provides a `step` function, which runs the computation until it calls the magical `yield` function. Here the computation is paused, returning to the caller enough information to resume the computation later.

For extra awesomness: Allow the caller to modify the state between `step` calls. (The type signatures above ought to allow this, for example.)

---

Use case: It's often easy to write code that does something complex, but a total PITA to transform it to also *output* the intermediate states in its operation. If you want the user to be able to *change* something mid-way through execution, things get complex really fast.

Implementation ideas:

- *Obviously* it can be done with threads, locks and `IO`. But can we do better? ;-)
- Something insane with a continuation monad?
- Maybe some kind of writer monad, where `yield` just logs the current state, and then we can "pretend" to `step` it by iterating over the states in the log. (Obviously this precludes altering the state between steps, since we're not really "pausing" anything now.)

Comment: No more insane than any other `Cont` instance, I'd think; poke at `callCC`.

Comment: In the first instance, I'd try constructing the free monad on the signature {mutate :: (s -> s) -> (); yield :: () -> ()}.

Comment: GHC had a monad you could _resume_ (ResumeT) but for some reason it disappeared around version 6.8 I think.

Comment: It's unusual to see this many really great answers in an SO question. :-D

Comment: It is because you posted your question as a challenge. "Monads are awesome but can they do X!!??" to which the community responded with "Why YES! Yes they can!!"

Comment: Is the `yield` action similar to Python's `yield`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Sure; you just let any computation either finish with a result, or suspend itself, giving an action to be used on resume, along with the state at the time:

```
data Pause s a = Pause { runPause :: s -> (PauseResult s a, s) }

data PauseResult s a
    = Done a
    | Suspend (Pause s a)

instance Monad (Pause s) where
    return a = Pause (\s -> (Done a, s))
    m >>= k = Pause $ \s ->
        case runPause m s of
            (Done a, s') -> runPause (k a) s'
            (Suspend m', s') -> (Suspend (m' >>= k), s')

get :: Pause s s
get = Pause (\s -> (Done s, s))

put :: s -> Pause s ()
put s = Pause (\_ -> (Done (), s))

yield :: Pause s ()
yield = Pause (\s -> (Suspend (return ()), s))

step :: Pause s () -> s -> (Maybe (Pause s ()), s)
step m s =
    case runPause m s of
        (Done _, s') -> (Nothing, s')
        (Suspend m', s') -> (Just m', s')
```

The `Monad` instance just sequences things in the normal way, passing the final result to the `k` continuation, or adding the rest of the computation to be done on suspension.

Comment: Points for including `get` and `put` and hence fulfilling the spirit as well as the letter of the original question :)

Comment: It is easy to see from this implementation that `step` could be enhanced to the type signature `Pause s x -> s -> (Either x (Pause s x), s)`. Just change the line `(Done x , s') -> (Left x, s')` and change `Just` to `Right` on the following line. Indeed, ParseResult s a === Either a (Pause s a)

Comment: Very nicely done. I forgot I need `get`. (I don't actually need `put`, only `mutate`, but that's easy.) This is a very nice answer.

Answer (score 68):

Note: that you provided yourself no direct access to the current state `s` in this monad.

`Pause s` is just a free monad over the `mutate` and `yield` operations. Implemented directly you get:

```
data Pause s a
  = Return a
  | Mutate (s -> s) (Pause s a)
  | Yield (Pause s a)

instance Monad (Pause s) where
  return = Return
  Return a   >>= k = k a
  Mutate f p >>= k = Mutate f (p >>= k)
  Yield p    >>= k = Yield (p >>= k)
```

with a couple of smart constructors to give you the desired API:

```
mutate :: (s -> s) -> Pause s ()
mutate f = Mutate f (return ())

yield :: Pause s ()
yield = Yield (return ())
```

and the step function to drive it

```
step :: s -> Pause s () -> (s, Maybe (Pause s ()))
step s (Mutate f k) = step (f s) k
step s (Return ()) = (s, Nothing)
step s (Yield k) = (s, Just k)
```

You could also define this directly using

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))
```

(from my 'free' package) with

```
data Op s a = Mutate (s -> s) a | Yield a
```

then we already have a monad for Pause

```
type Pause s = Free (Op s)
```

and just need to define the smart constructors and stepper.

**Making it faster.**

Now, these implementations are easy to reason about, but they don't have the fastest operational model. In particular, left associated uses of (>>=) yield asymptotically slower code.

To get around that you can apply the [Codensity](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/kan-extensions/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Codensity.html) monad to your existing free monad, or just use the ['Church free'](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/kan-extensions/2.1.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html) monad directly, both of which I describe in depth on my blog.

http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less/

http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less-2/

http://comonad.com/reader/2011/free-monads-for-less-3/

The result of applying the Church encoded version of the Free monad is that you get an easy to reason about model for the data type, and you still get a fast evaluation model.

Comment: There is a great deal of awesomeness in this answer. Where can I read more about free monads ? (I know there is stuff in "data types à la carte", but I'm looking for more)

Comment: Very nice. Although I liked ehird better. I'll check out the blog references later...

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Free_structure introduces free monads reasonably well. I talk about them quite a bit on my blog as well, but the relevant content there is more diffuse.

Comment: free monad tutorial: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html

Answer (score 34):

Here's how I'd go about it, using *free* monads. Er, um, what are they? They're trees with actions at the nodes and values at the leaves, with `>>=` acting like tree grafting.

```
data f :^* x
  = Ret x
  | Do (f (f :^* x))
```

It's not unusual to write F<sup>*</sup>X for such a thing in the mathematics, hence my cranky infix type name. To make an instance, you just need `f` to be something you can map over: any `Functor` will do.

```
instance Functor f => Monad ((:^*) f) where
  return = Ret
  Ret x  >>= k  = k x
  Do ffx >>= k  = Do (fmap (>>= k) ffx)
```

That's just "apply `k` at all the leaves and graft in the resulting trees". These can trees represent *strategies* for interactive computation: the whole tree covers every possible interaction with the environment, and the environment chooses which path in the tree to follow. Why are they *free*? They're just trees, with no interesting equational theory on them, saying which strategies are equivalent to which other strategies.

Now let's have a kit for making Functors which correspond to a bunch of commands we might want to be able to do. This thing

```
data (:>>:) s t x = s :? (t -> x)

instance Functor (s :>>: t) where
  fmap k (s :? f) = s :? (k . f)
```

captures the idea of getting a value in `x` after *one* command with input type `s` and output type `t`. To do that, you need to choose an input in `s` and explain how to continue to the value in `x` given the command's output in `t`. To map a function across such a thing, you tack it onto the continuation. So far, standard equipment. For our problem, we may now define two functors:

```
type Modify s  = (s -> s) :>>: ()
type Yield     = () :>>: ()
```

It's like I've just written down the value types for the commands we want to be able to do!

Now let's make sure we can offer a *choice* between those commands. We can show that a choice between functors yields a functor. More standard equipment.

```
data (:+:) f g x = L (f x) | R (g x)

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (f :+: g) where
  fmap k (L fx) = L (fmap k fx)
  fmap k (R gx) = R (fmap k gx)
```

So, `Modify s :+: Yield` represents the choice between modifying and yielding. Any *signature* of simple commands (communicating with the world in terms of values rather than manipulating computations) can be turned into a functor this way. It's a bother that I have to do it by hand!

That gives me your monad: the free monad over the signature of modify and yield.

```
type Pause s = (:^*) (Modify s :+: Yield)
```

I can define the modify and yield commands as one-do-then-return. Apart from negotiating the dummy input for `yield`, that's just mechanical.

```
mutate :: (s -> s) -> Pause s ()
mutate f = Do (L (f :? Ret))

yield :: Pause s ()
yield = Do (R (() :? Ret))
```

The `step` function then gives a meaning to the strategy trees. It's a *control operator*, constructing one computation (maybe) from another.

```
step :: s -> Pause s () -> (s, Maybe (Pause s ()))
step s (Ret ())            = (s, Nothing)
step s (Do (L (f  :? k)))  = step (f s) (k ())
step s (Do (R (() :? k)))  = (s, Just (k ()))
```

The `step` function runs the strategy until either it finishes with a `Ret`, or it yields, mutating the state as it goes.

The general method goes like this: separate the *commands* (interacting in terms of values) from the *control operators* (manipulating computations); build the free monad of "strategy trees" over the signature of commands (cranking the handle); implement the control operators by recursion over the strategy trees.

Comment: I thought it might be useful to expose the pattern and build the kit that lets you just instantiate it. Of course it's pretty unpleasant to work with (Do (L (f :? k))) patterns. That's something I usually make more readable with "pattern synonyms". Following this pattern (or its swifter elaborations) ought to be less work. Perhaps I will make it so.

Comment: Definitely the most abstract. Personally I had trouble following it, but I'm sure someone somewhere will find it fascinating.

Comment: Is there a possibility to reduce the amount of L (L (L R) somehow? 

I made a monad with 5 commands and the syntax gets a bit difficult to work with. (Especially if I want my monad to do 10 different things). 

But that is a minor thing. I find this very useful.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I usually use pattern synonyms to hide the cruft. Otherwise, DeriveFunctor might do enough for your purposes. See also "Datatypes a la Carte" and "Unembedding Domain Specific Languages" for helpful type class hackery when working with extensible sums.

Answer (score 14):

Doesn't match your type signatures exactly, but certainly simple:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}
import Control.Monad.State

newtype ContinuableT m a = Continuable { runContinuable :: m (Either a (ContinuableT m a)) }
instance Monad m => Monad (ContinuableT m) where
    return = Continuable . return . Left
    Continuable m >>= f = Continuable $ do
        v <- m
        case v of
            Left  a -> runContinuable (f a)
            Right b -> return (Right (b >>= f))

instance MonadTrans ContinuableT where
    lift m = Continuable (liftM Left m)

instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (ContinuableT m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put

yield :: Monad m => ContinuableT m a -> ContinuableT m a
yield = Continuable . return . Right

step :: ContinuableT (State s) a -> s -> (Either a (ContinuableT (State s) a), s)
step = runState . runContinuable

-- mutate unnecessary, just use modify
```

Answer (score 11):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
newtype Pause s x = Pause (s -> (s, Either x (Pause s x)))

instance Monad (Pause s) where
  return x = Pause (, Left x)

  Pause k >>= f = Pause $ \s -> let (s', v) = k s in
                                case v of
                                  Left x -> step (f x) s'
                                  Right x -> (s', Right (x >>= f))

mutate :: (s -> s) -> Pause s ()
mutate f = Pause (\s -> (f s, Left ()))

yield :: Pause s ()
yield = Pause (, Right (return ()))

step :: Pause s x -> s -> (s, Either x (Pause s x))
step (Pause x) = x
```

That's how I would wrote this. I gave `step` a bit more general definition, it could be as well named `runPause`. In fact thinking about type of `step` lead me to definition of `Pause`.

In the [monad-coroutine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-coroutine) package you will find a general monad transformer. The `Pause s` monad is the same as `Coroutine (State s) Id`. You can combine coroutines with other monads.

Related: the Prompt monad in http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/issue15.pdf

Answer (score 11):

Note: This answer is [available](https://gist.github.com/3552390) as a literate Haskell file at Gist.

I quite enjoyed this exercise. I tried to do it without looking at the answers, and it was worth it. It took me considerable time, but the result is surprisingly close to two of the other answers, as well as to [monad-coroutine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-coroutine) library. So I guess this is somewhat natural solution to this problem. Without this exercise, I wouldn't understand how *monad-coroutine* really works.

To add some additional value, I'll explain the steps that eventually led me to the solution.

**Recognizing the state monad**

Since we're dealing with states, it we look for patterns that can be effectively described by the state monad. In particular, `s -    s` is isomorphic to `s -> (s, ())`, so it could be replaced by `State s ()`. And function of type `s -> x -> (s, y)` can be flipped to `x -> (s -> (s, y))`, which is actually `x -> State s y`. This leads us to updated signatures

```
mutate :: State s () -    Pause s ()
step   :: Pause s () -    State s (Maybe (Pause s ()))
```

**Generalization**

Our `Pause` monad is currently parametrized by the state. However, now we see that we don't really need the state for anything, nor we use any specifics of the state monad. So we could try to make a more general solution that is parametrized by any monad:

```
mutate :: (Monad m) =    m () -> Pause m ()
yield  :: (Monad m) =    Pause m ()
step   :: (Monad m) =    Pause m () -> m (Maybe (Pause m ()))
```

Also, we could try to make `mutate` and `step` more general by allowing any kind of value, not just `()`. And by realizing that `Maybe a` is isomorphic to `Either a ()` we can finally generalize our signatures to

```
mutate :: (Monad m) =    m a -> Pause m a
yield  :: (Monad m) =    Pause m ()
step   :: (Monad m) =    Pause m a -> m (Either (Pause m a) a)
```

so that `step` returns the intermediate value of the computation.

**Monad transformer**

Now, we see that we're actually trying to make a monad from a monad - add some additional functionality. This is what is usually called a [monad transformer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers). Moreover, `mutate`'s signature is exactly the same as [lift](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v%3alift) from `MonadTrans`. Most likely, we're on the right track.

**The final monad**

The `step` function seems to be the most important part of our monad, it defines just what we need. Perhaps, this could be the new data structure? Let's try:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans

data Pause m a
    = Pause { step :: m (Either (Pause m a) a) }
```

If the `Either` part is `Right`, it's just a monadic value, without any
suspensions. This leads us how to implement the easist thing - the `lift`
function from `MonadTrans`:

```
instance MonadTrans Pause where
    lift k = Pause (liftM Right k)
```

and `mutate` is simply a specialization:

```
mutate :: (Monad m) => m () -> Pause m ()
mutate = lift
```

If the `Either` part is `Left`, it represents the continued computation after a suspension. So let's create a function for that:

```
suspend :: (Monad m) => Pause m a -> Pause m a
suspend = Pause . return . Left
```

Now `yield`ing a computation is simple, we just suspend with an empty
computation:

```
yield :: (Monad m) => Pause m ()
yield = suspend (return ())
```

Still, we're missing the most important part. The `Monad` instance. Let's fix
it. Implementing `return` is simple, we just lift the inner monad. Implementing `>>=` is a bit trickier. If the original `Pause` value was only a simple value (`Right y`), then we just wrap `f y` as the result. If it is a paused computation that can be continued (`Left p`), we recursively descend into it.

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (Pause m) where
    return x = lift (return x) -- Pause (return (Right x))
    (Pause s) >>= f
        = Pause $ s >>= \x -> case x of
            Right y     -> step (f y)
            Left p      -> return (Left (p >>= f))
```

**Testing**

Let's try to make some model function that uses and updates state, yielding
while inside the computation:

```
test1 :: Int -> Pause (State Int) Int
test1 y = do
            x <- lift get
            lift $ put (x * 2)
            yield
            return (y + x)
```

And a helper function that debugs the monad - prints its intermediate steps to
the console:

```
debug :: Show s => s -> Pause (State s) a -> IO (s, a)
debug s p = case runState (step p) s of
                (Left next, s')     ->  print s' >> debug s' next
                (Right r, s')       ->  return (s', r)    

main :: IO ()
main = do
    debug 1000 (test1 1 >>= test1 >>= test1) >>= print
```

The result is

```
2000
4000
8000
(8000,7001)
```

as expected.

**Coroutines and *monad-coroutine***

What we have implemented is a quite general monadic solution that implements [Coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine). Perhaps not surprisingly, someone had the idea before :-), and created the [monad-coroutine](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-coroutine) package. Less surprisingly, it's quite similar to what we created.

The package generalizes the idea even further. The continuing computation is stored inside an arbitrary functor. This allows [suspend](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-coroutine/0.7.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Coroutine.html#v%3asuspend) many variations how to work with suspended computations. For example, to [pass a value](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-coroutine/0.7.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Coroutine-SuspensionFunctors.html#v%3ayield) to the caller of [resume](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-coroutine/0.7.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Coroutine.html#v%3aresume) (which we called `step`), or to [wait for a value](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-coroutine/0.7.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Coroutine-SuspensionFunctors.html#v%3aawait) to be provided to continue, etc.