# Pause Monad - What should the monadic type look like?

Tags: f#, monads

The typical Pause monad implementation that I see looks like this (based on Chapter 5 from Friendly F# by Giulia Costantini and Giuseppe Maggiore).

```
open System

type Process<'a> = unit -> 'a Step
and Step<'a> =
| Continue of 'a
| Paused of 'a Process

type PauseMonad () =
    member this.Return x = fun () -> Continue x
    member this.ReturnFrom x = x
    member this.Bind (result, rest) =
        fun () ->
            match result () with
            | Continue x -> rest x ()
            | Paused p -> Paused (this.Bind (p, rest))

let yield_ () =
    fun () ->
        Paused (fun () ->
            Continue ())

let get_process_step process_ step = do printfn "Process %d, step %d." process_ step
let get_last_process_step process_ = do printfn "Process %d finished." process_

let rec get_process process_ step_count =
    PauseMonad () {
        do! yield_ ()
        if step_count = 0 then
            do get_last_process_step process_
            return ()
        else
            do get_process_step process_ step_count
            return! get_process process_ <| step_count - 1
    }

let rec race p1 p2 =
    match p1 (), p2 () with
    | Continue _, _ -> do printfn "Process 1 finished first."
    | _, Continue _ -> do printfn "Process 2 finished first."
    | Paused p1_, Paused p2_ -> race (p1_) (p2_)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let process_1 = get_process 1 5
    let process_2 = get_process 2 7
    do race process_1 process_2
    0
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236953/the-pause-monad/10237311#10237311) is a similar implementation in Haskell.

However, it seems simpler to get rid of the mutually recursive types Process and Step, and just use a single recursive type, Process, as follows.

```
open System

type Process<'a> =
| Continue of 'a
| Paused of (unit -> 'a Process)

type PauseMonad () =
    member this.Return x = Continue x
    member this.ReturnFrom x = x
    member this.Bind (result, rest) =
        match result with
        | Continue x -> Paused (fun () -> rest x)
        | Paused p -> Paused (fun () -> this.Bind (p (), rest))

let yield_ () =
    Paused (fun () ->
        Continue ())

let get_process_step process_ step = do printfn "Process %d, step %d." process_ step
let get_last_process_step process_ = do printfn "Process %d finished." process_

let rec get_process process_ step_count =
    PauseMonad () {
        do! yield_ ()
        if step_count = 0 then
            do get_last_process_step process_
            return ()
        else
            do get_process_step process_ step_count
            return! get_process process_ <| step_count - 1
    }

let rec race p1 p2 =
    match p1, p2 with
    | Continue _, _ -> do printfn "Process 1 finished first."
    | _, Continue _ -> do printfn "Process 2 finished first."
    | Paused p1_, Paused p2_ -> race (p1_ ()) (p2_ ())

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let process_1 = get_process 1 5
    let process_2 = get_process 2 7
    do race process_1 process_2
    0
```

Either of these implementations gives me the same output:

```
Process 1, step 5.
Process 2, step 7.
Process 1, step 4.
Process 2, step 6.
Process 1, step 3.
Process 2, step 5.
Process 1, step 2.
Process 2, step 4.
Process 1, step 1.
Process 2, step 3.
Process 1 finished.
Process 2, step 2.
Process 1 finished first.
```

I've made the two implementations as similar as possible to facilitate differencing. As far as I can tell, the only differences are these:

1. In the first version, yield_, PauseMonad.Return, and PauseMonad.Bind add delays to the return values. In the second version, PauseMonad.Return adds the delay inside the Paused wrapper.
2. In the first version, PauseMonad.Bind runs one step of the result process to see whether the return value matches Continue or Paused. In the second version, PauseMonad.Bind runs one step of the result process only after determining that it matches Paused.
3. In the first version, race runs one step of each process, checks that both results match Paused, and recurses with the remaining processes. In the second version, race checks that both processes match Paused, then runs one step of each process, and recurses with the return values of these steps.

Is there a reason the first version is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting code from Haskell to F# is a bit tricky, because Haskell is lazy and so whenever you see any value, say `'a` in Haskell, you could interpret it as `unit -> 'a` (or more precisely, as `Lazy<'a>`) - so everything is delayed implicitly.

But let's just compare the two definitions in F#:

```
// Process is always delayed
type Process1<'a> = unit -> 'a Step1
and Step1<'a> = Continue1 of 'a | Paused1 of 'a Process1

// Process is a value or a delayed computation
type Process2<'a> = Continue2 of 'a | Paused2 of (unit -> 'a Process2)
```

The key difference is that when you want to represent a computation that produces a value immediately, this has to be a fully evaluated value in the first case, but it can be a function that does something and returns a value in the second case. For example:

```
let primitive1 : Process1<int> = fun () ->
  printfn "hi!"    // This will print when the computation is evaluated
  Continue1(42) )

let primitive2 : Process2<int> = 
  printfn "hi!"    // This will print immediately and returns a monadic value
  Continue2(42)
```

This becomes interesting when you add `Delay` member to the computations, which lets you write things like the following *without* evaluating the side-effects:

```
process { 
  printfn "Hi" // Using Process1, we can easily delay this
               // Using Process2, this is trickier (or we run it immediately)
  return 42 }
```

There is lot to be said about this and you can find more information [in a recent article I wrote about computation expressions](http://tomasp.net/academic/papers/computation-zoo/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tomas. You're right, I should be careful about what I call a "similar" Haskell implementation.
I gather from your answer that which definition I should use is relative to the situation and that the first definition is not necessarily the "canonical" one for a Pause monad?
Thank you and I will peruse that article once again though I'm afraid it starts going over my head halfway through section 3.2. :)